# How to find prediction interval or visualize q-q plot for log pearson type III distribution

Tags: r, python, prediction-interval

In flood analysis, return period and streamflow values are estimated using log person type III distribution. And we use different libraries to do that, but I can't find how to plot the prediction interval for the estimated values.

For example, using python library [`scipy.stats.pearson3`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearson3.html), the confidence interval given by the function `interval` is for estimated parameter. I want to know the prediction interval for the estimated values for different quantiles.

```
floods = [15000, 51500, 93000, 58200, 16200, 42400, 50600, 48000, 28100,
          47600, 51300, 34700, 79100, 50900, 77600, 68900, 71800, 67600]

fit_params = distribution.fit(t.annual_max)
distribution.isf([1/2, 1/5, 1/10, 1/100], *fit_params)
# [53467.48606707, 70442.88750954, 79010.09568304, 98528.08393265]
```

Here, we have estimated values for 2 year flood, to 100 year flood, but considering we have only 18 data points, there should be higher uncertainty for 100 year flood compared to 10 year flood. But I don't see any functions to calculate that.

And I thought if I look at qq plot, or plot the actual quantiles for the data to see how much data density the predicted places have, but can't figure that out either.

Here, the Red dots would be the points in the example (I only know the x axis i.e. their value I don't know how to calculate the quantiles i.e. y axis), the Blue line would be the fitted log pearson III distribution (which we can get from many libraries). And green area would be the prediction interval that I want.

[image]

I also looked at the R package [`LogPearsonIII`](https://rdrr.io/github/USGS-R/smwrBase/man/LogPearsonIII.html) but couldn't find it. I couldn't even find any plots with the shaded area showing the uncertainty in the prediction in image search. So I'm asking the question here.